# Python - Print combobox value in ONE label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

how can I create a label that contains values, of selected values from combo1 and combo2. and not 2 separate label (A_ANA , A_AGR or B_AGR etc.) ?

I want to be able to generate names like A_ANA or B_ana etc. on that label

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class LabeledCombobox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, dictionary, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kw)
        self.dictionary = dictionary

        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=sorted(list(dictionary.keys())),
                                  state='readonly')
        self.combo.current(0)
        self.combo.pack(fill="both")
        self.combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.on_selection)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.value())
        self.label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


    def value(self):
        return self.dictionary[self.combo.get()]

    def on_selection(self, event=None):  # Just to test
        self.label.config(text=self.value())


lookup = {'Arkitekt': 'A', 'Geoteknik': 'B',
          'Ingeniør Anlæg': 'C', 'Procesanlæg': 'D'}

documentcode = {'Aftaler': 'AGR', 'Analyse': 'ANA',
                'Myndigheder': 'AUT', 'Sagsbasis': 'BAS'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Labeled comboboxes")

    combo1 = LabeledCombobox(root, lookup, bd=1, relief="groove")
    combo1.pack(side="left", padx=(2, 2), pady=5)
    combo2 = LabeledCombobox(root, documentcode, bd=1, relief="groove")
    combo2.pack(side="right", padx=(2, 2), pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question? Telling us what you want isn't a question, you need to ask about some specific part of the solution.

Comment: How can I make a label showing selected values ​​from selected combobox. something like A_AGR

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the values from the two comboboxes, combine them into a single string, and then modify the label using the configure method (or updating an associated `StringVar` if you're  using one):

```
newlabel = "%s_%s" % (combo1.value(), combo2.value())
label.configure(text=newlabel)
```